# SQL Server EER diagram error - Open University Learning Analytics dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-relationship

I try to create the EER of the dataset described [here](https://analyse.kmi.open.ac.uk/open_dataset#examples) but I get the error shown in the 2nd screenshot. What am I doing wrong?

[image: EER Diagram]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Very clear error message.

> student_info table
>
> Unable to create index **PK_Student_info**
>
> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a **duplicate key** was found

You cannot create that PK why

1. The PK is unique
2. There are more than one record with the same key

Probable you tried to set the Student **ID column** as unique in that table and by looking at the select we clearly see two records with that very same value.

Clearly you do need to create a **NOT UNIQUE** index on that column.
Note by default PK are unique. Also note it's not a good idea to use `id_student` as a PK the case that table can get many records for the same student.

If the problem is just duplucated records, delete one record but it really depends on your schema and app requisites.

Looks like you can use composite key with student_info, code_module, code_presentetion (considering it's valid to have "duplicated" records in student_info).